# php - Combine arrays based on specific order

Tags: php, arrays

I want to combine 2 arrays, but I want the order of elements to based on the index value that is stored in another array.

```
$old = array("aaa", "ccc", "ddd");
$oldPos = array(0, 2, 3);
$new = array("bbb", "eee");
$combinedArr = //This is where I need help combining the $old and $new based on the logic explained below.
```

`$oldPos` contains the index number that corresponds to each element in the `$old` array. So in this example, "aaa" would be in index 0 of the new array, "ccc" would be in index 2 and "ddd" would be in index 3.

$combinedArr should print out:

```
"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"
```

Comment: So, have you tried anything?

Comment: You probably need to know ho `array_combine` works http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php and also the `+` (union) operator for arrays http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Comment: @Nima I cannot simply combine the 2 arrays because the position depends on the values of a 3rd array

Comment: How would the new array added know what position to take?

Comment: @Matt9Atkins I think you should add more details to your question. You only described the logic used to create a new array from `$old` and `$oldPos` and `array_combine` solves that. But what about `$new`? What is the logic used to combine two arrays? Here `$new[0]` already has a value `"bbb"` what should happen here?

Comment: To make things clear for future readers, the methods that are using `foreach/for/while` assume that the `$oldPos` values are in ascending order -- if they are not, then these methods break.  sevavietl's answer and my answer will not break under these conditions and do not require any pre-sorting.  (This may be an unnecessary feature for the OP, but I just wanted to explain the point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this one will be helpful.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/845672)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$old = array("aaa", "ccc", "ddd");
$oldPos = array(0, 2, 3);
$new = array("bbb", "eee");

$count=count($old)+count($new); // count of the no of elements of both the array.

$arrayFlip=  array_flip($oldPos);//flipping the array over values
$combined=array();
for($x=0;$x<$count;$x++)
{
    if(isset($arrayFlip[$x]))
    {
       $combined[$x]= current($old);//using current element of array
       unset($old[key($old)]);//unsetting current element of array
    }
    else
    {
        $combined[$x]= current($new);//using current element of array
        unset($new[key($new)]);//unsetting current element of array
    }
}
print_r($combined);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). For values, just glue two arrays together with [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). For keys, firstly, get the whole range of resulting array size using [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php), then remove taken keys (the ones from 
 `$oldPos`) with [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). And once again glue together `$oldPos` and resulting difference. That array will be your positions. In the end, you might want to sort array by keys using [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

```
$old = array("aaa", "ccc", "ddd");
$oldPos = array(0, 2, 3);
$new = array("bbb", "eee");

$combinedArr = array_combine(
    array_merge(
        $oldPos,
        // Deduce keys for new array elements substacting $oldPos
        // from the whole range
        array_diff(range(0, count($old) + count($new) -1), $oldPos)
    ),
    array_merge($old, $new)    
);
ksort($combinedArr);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fb1f01659048e35e72a9f5b58ded7771f40be19b).

Such approach saves you from using explicit loops (which unless you are micro optimization person is a great thing) and ensures you take as much from standard PHP library as you can.

Comment: After seeing all of the loopy methods, I was going to post a loopless method.  And as I scrolled down to paste my code into the textbox, I see that sevavietl has beaten me to it!  Great answer +1.  My snippet has one less function call (`count()`), but more variables (I think it is easier to follow this way).  If anyone is slightly lost with this answer, my demo is the same thing written differently.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0dd6cf61f4941df8a3cf3002336d587e304d27c7

Answer (score 1):

This relies on the arrays all being sorted correctly (although I think that's a limit of what you're trying to do anyway)

```
<?php
$old = ["aaa", "ccc", "ddd"];
$oldPos = [0, 2, 3];
$new = ["bbb", "eee"];

$combinedArr = [];
$i = 0;

// Keep looping until we've exhausted both arrays
while (count($old) + count($new) > 0) {
    // If $i matches an entry in $oldPos, grab the entry from $old, otherwise from $new
    $combinedArr[] = in_array($i, $oldPos) ? array_shift($old) : array_shift($new);
    $i++;
}

print_r($combinedArr); // ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"]
```

Comment: @Matt9Atkins iainn is correct about the order, see what happens when `$oldPos` is not in ASC  order: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/834b889b6ffb06d2493aa2f90d4fba38a2f3677e  If you want to use a for/while loop, iainn's method intelligently calls `array_shift()` (Sahil missed this suitable function call).  However, because iainn's two `count() calls are not cached, the two calls are required on each iteration. Despite being more intuitive, `in_array()` may be a little slower than `isset()` (not that the end user will be able to tell in data sets of this size) when checking old keys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$old = array("aaa", "ccc", "ddd");
$oldPos = array(0, 2, 3);
$new = array("bbb", "eee");

$oldKeys = array_combine($oldPos, $old);

foreach ($new as $key => $val) {
  $curKey = $key;
  while (isset($oldKeys[$curKey])) {
   $curKey++;
  }
  $oldKeys[$curKey] = $val;
}

sort($oldKeys);
var_dump($oldKeys);
```

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers, please improve your answer with some comments at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

Hold the phone, I found a more direct approach using `array_multisort()` this means you don't have to stitch the merged keys to the merged values.  This uses 6 function calls compared to the 7-function method that I commented under sevavietl's answer.

I changed the values in the `old` and `new` arrays to distinguish that the output array is not being ordered alphabetically (the OP's sample data may cause some confusion to future readers).

[Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec6f8d02f4191b3f6a79a5b1716214a69b7812c7)

Demonstration #1: verbose style

```
$oldvals = array("Last", "Fourth", "Second");
$oldkeys = array(4, 3, 1);
$newvals = array("First", "Third");

$vals=array_merge($oldvals,$newvals);  // forge one array with old elements first and new elements second
$newkeys=array_diff(range(0,sizeof($vals)-1),$oldkeys); // generate all necessary keys, omit "old" keys
$keys=array_merge($oldkeys,$newkeys);  // forge one array with old keys first and new keys second (as values)
array_multisort($keys,$vals);  // sort unordered keys and unordered vals in the same fashion
var_export($vals);
```

Demonstration #2: condensed style

```
$oldvals=['First','Third','Fourth'];
$oldkeys=[0,2,3];
$newvals=['Second','Last'];

$vals=array_merge($oldvals,$newvals);
array_multisort(array_merge($oldkeys,array_diff(range(0,sizeof($vals)-1),$oldkeys)),$vals);
var_export($vals);
```

Output from either code block:

```
array (
  0 => 'First',
  1 => 'Second',
  2 => 'Third',
  3 => 'Fourth',
  4 => 'Last',
)
```

---

Here is a looping `for` loop method that will not break on unordered `$oldkeys` values. [Demo with test of OP's data, and unordered data](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a36ef241d314cc38a509508404d11270770fed79)

```
$oldvals = array("Last", "Fourth", "Second");
$oldkeys = array(4, 3, 1);
$newvals = array("First", "Third");

for($i=0, $count=sizeof($oldvals)+sizeof($newvals); $i<$count; ++$i){
    $result[$i]=(($k=array_search($i,$oldkeys))!==false?$oldvals[$k]:array_shift($newvals));
}
var_export($result); // same result as my earlier method
```